# How to avoid parseerror when the JSON response delivered by PHP includes a single-quote or apostrophe?

Tags: php, ajax, json, jquery

Suppose I have a PHP script that returns a json response.  It looks something like this:

```
$ctype = ContentNego::desiredContentType();
header("Content-Type: $ctype");

if (ContentNego::flavor($ctype) == ContentFlavor::JSON) {
    echo '{ "name": "' . $name . '", ' .
        '"comment": "' . $comment . '"}';
}
.... other content types here....
```

Prior to the code above, I have

```
class ContentFlavor {
    const XML = 1;
    const JSON = 2;
    const TEXT = 3;
    const Unknown = 4;
}
```

And the value of `$cftype` is set by examining the incoming Accept header, in a basic form of content-type negotiation.

The string echoed by the php script looks like this:

```
[ "name" : "Vettel", "comment" : "He's terrific" ]
```

In the browser, I have javascript like this:

```
    $.ajax({type: "GET",
            url: url,
            dataType: "json",
            headers : { "Accept" : 'application/json' },
            cache: false,
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                enableEditboxButtons();
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                // fill and show the editbox dialog
                ...
            }});
```

But when I receive this content on the jQuery side, I get this:

```
[ "name" : "Vettel", "comment" : "He\'s terrific" ]
```

Notice the injected backslash "escaping" the apostrophe or single-quote.  My code did not put that backslash there.  It seems to have been injected by PHP?  Also it seems to be against the requirements of JSON encoding as stipulated on http://json.org:

[image]

The resulting json string with the escaped apostrophe fails to parse in jQuery 1.7.1, and my error fn gets called.

What's the deal?  Is PHP really doing this escaping, and if so why/how?  (It runs on PHP 5.2.17 on Linux)  Can I avoid it?

If not, how can I work around this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cheeso, make sure the *magic_quotes_gpc* and *magic_quotes_runtime* option is turned off on the PHP configuration (that could be putting the backslash there, more info [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc)).

Also you probably should use the [json_encode](http://www.php.net/json_encode) method if you can, it makes life a lot easier as you can pass an array or object directly to it and get a JSON version of the represented data.

Answer (score 0):

I searched and found [this](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8320#comment:3).

I put this code in my browser-side script, it runs once on document-ready.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    // Apparently, when sending application/json, if there is a
    // single-quote contained in a string value, PHP erroneously escapes
    // it.  This causes jQuery to barf with a parsererror.
    //
    // To work around the problem, use a custom converter to fixup
    // that invalid json serialization.
    //
    // e.g. { "comment": "Grandma\'s sweater" } -->
    //          { "comment": "Grandma's sweater" }
    converters: {
        "text json": function (textValue) {
            return jQuery.parseJSON(textValue.replace(/(^|[^\\])\\'/g, "$1'"));
        }
    }
});
```

I'm still not clear on how or why the apostrophe creeps in there, but this strips it out, when JSON is received by the browser.

Comment: Pay no attention to this answer. Nathan's answer is better.